# Can't find the specific tag using .find() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am stacked with this problem, I want to know if the 'li' have a child 'ul'. I console (using the onclick event attached to the 'span' element) all the children of 'li' (using the .children() method) and 'ul' is listed but when I use .find() method it return 0 of length.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/><span>LIST ONE</span></li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox"/> <span>LIST TWO</span>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox"/> <span onclick="myFunc(this)">SUB LIST ONE</span></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"/> <span>SUB LIST TWO</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function myFunc(el){
     var x = $(el).parent(); //the li
     var xx = $(x).parent().parent(); //the parent the ul 
     console.log($(xx).children()); //ul will be listed here
     console.log($(xx).children().find('ul')); //this return 0 length which I believe ul is not found
}
```

What really happen here? Thank you for your help! (jquery newbee)

Comment: `var x` and `xx` are jquery variables, and when you logging call `$(xx)` jquery again when it spect a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use `$('xx').find('ul')` to find the ul or `$('xx').closest('ul')`

Comment: the .closest('ul') method return the parent ul of the li what if I want to get the only ul child of the li? Thank you!

Comment: $(el).closest('ul') will get the child ul

Comment: Thank you! I just missed something. Good day!

Answer (score 0):

You're being far too obnoxious in your code, this solution isn't scalable, but it works in this example, as in, how to select your `ul`

```
function myFunc(el){
    // Grabs the <span> tag
    var x = $(el).parent().parent();
    // Creates a jQuery object out of the list item above.
    console.log(x)
}
```